# Configure NIC on boot of FreeBSD 12

Tags: networking, drivers, freebsd

We need to configure NIC for better performance of our application on FreeBSD 12. System is
`FreeBSD 12.0-RELEASE-p3 GENERIC  amd64`

To start, I would like to show our solution for Linux system. For setup 16 RX and 16 TX queues on our multi-queue NIC we apply command `ethtool -L ens786f1 combined 16`. We are looking for alternative call for FreeBSD system.

On FreeBSD, our NIC is driven by `ixl` driver. I have found some kernel variables that should do the same thing like `override_qs_enable`, `override_nrxqs` and `override_ntxqs` (here is the [manpage](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=iflib&apropos=0&sektion=4&manpath=FreeBSD%2012.0-RELEASE%20and%20Ports&arch=default&format=html)). Command to set them would look like `sysctl dev.ixl.1.iflib.override_qs_enable="1"` and so on (`ens786f1` and `ixl1` is the same device with different interface on different system).

I would like to set these variables every time on boot. Manpage says that these variables have to be set on boot before the `ixl` driver is loaded (using loader), so I added setup lines into `/boot/loader.conf`. The file was empty before,
so now it looks like:

```
#Setup NIC#
dev.ixl.1.iflib.override_qs_enable="1"
dev.ixl.1.iflib.override_nrxqs="16"
dev.ixl.1.iflib.override_ntxqs="16"
```

`/boot/defaults/loader.conf` included `/boot/loader.conf` using `loader_conf_files`, so my boot file should be running. But when I reboot and look at the variables using `sysctl`, these variables are default (0) and when I look at `dmesg`, device is not setup the way I wanted (still shows 8 RX and 8 TX queues).

It's possible that /boot/loader.conf is not called; maybe it's just bad approach to replace `ethtool` command on FreeBSD.

*Some logs*: [pastebin.com/YGTxqxdx](https://pastebin.com/YGTxqxdx)

---

I have also tried to set up variables using `kenv` (save in file also) but it seems that options aren't saved after a reboot.

---

After few days of research, I have found out that I probably have to set up new / edit old VF of my NIC using `iovctl`. When I call `iovctl -S -d ixl1`, there is a parameter `num-queues`. Does anyone have experience with this configuration?

---

Problem was with Loader - wrong loader setup in GRUB. Still, if you are looking for help regarding setting up a number of RX/TX queues with same driver, the answer below is a really good set of information.

Comment: Your first approach seems correct for me. `iovctl` is however for setting SR-IOV. The ixl driver supports this but is for I/O virtualization and allows the card to appear as multiple device. See [What is SR-IOV?](https://blog.scottlowe.org/2009/12/02/what-is-sr-iov/).

Comment: The card does appear as multiple device (ixl0 and ixl1) becouse it has more ports. But right now I'm totally desperate, so I'm trying any solution..

Comment: You should add the output of `sysctl dev.ixl hw.ixl hw.intr_storm_threshold`, `sysctl -d dev.ixl hw.ixl` and `dmesg | grep ^ixl` to your question. Reading the [ixl](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ixl) man page I am not sure that this driver uses iflib.
Maybe it is `hw.ixl.max_queues` you are looking for? Are you even sure you need to set the queues? The defaults might be OK on FreeBSD as the driver is not the same as on Linux.

You conflate 3 problems into 1: **a)** Fix a (unknown) performance issue **b)** Finding the correct tunable setting and **c)** making it persist.

Comment: I post logs on pasterbin, becouse they were realy long.. 
Im not sure where I obtain information that `iflib` is `ixl`s driver interface..
There is no `hw.ixl.max_queues` variable to setup.
In short, I'm looking for solution for adding more rxq/txq descriptors.
And yes, I need to find correct tunables and making them persist. But find the currect tunables is the main problem, making them persist should be secondary problem.  None fixing of performance issue, just tunning..

Comment: it would be really helpful if you added another answer explaining what setting you had in Grub - and whatever you did to fix it. It is nice with your short update in your question. But a full answer would be excellent. A question can have multiple fulfilling answers. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [How to make setting of kern.ipc.somaxconn persistent?](https://serverfault.com/questions/171797/how-to-make-setting-of-kern-ipc-somaxconn-persistent)

> Remove quotes "

```
dev.ixl.1.iflib.override_qs_enable=1
dev.ixl.1.iflib.override_nrxqs=16
dev.ixl.1.iflib.override_ntxqs=16
```

Test with `/etc/rc.d/sysctl start` or `service sysctl restart`

## Update:

In earlier versions of FreeBSD you would normally set `hw.ixl.max_queues`. But it seems that the ixl driver changed to using iflib with FreeBSD 12.

After `sysctl -d dev.ixl` we can indeed confirm that the driver is using [iflib](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=iflib)

```
dev.ixl.1.iflib.override_qs_enable: permit #txq != #rxq
dev.ixl.1.iflib.override_nrxqs: # of rxqs to use, 0 => use default #
dev.ixl.1.iflib.override_ntxqs: # of txqs to use, 0 => use default #
```

A web search confirms this as we can find the diff which adds it to the driver ([rS335338: ixl(4): Update to use iflib](https://reviews.freebsd.org/D15577)).

The settings are currently as default:

```
dev.ixl.1.iflib.override_qs_enable: 0
dev.ixl.1.iflib.override_nrxqs: 0
dev.ixl.1.iflib.override_ntxqs: 0
```

This should the set the number of queues to the number of cores (In this case 8). The [iflib](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=iflib) man page states that these must be set **before** loading the driver. Sysctl restart will then not help us - only reboots.

We must then set `/boot/loader.conf`:

```
dev.ixl.1.iflib.override_qs_enable=1
dev.ixl.1.iflib.override_nrxqs=16
dev.ixl.1.iflib.override_ntxqs=16
```

After setting this you should reboot and verify with `dmesg | grep ^ixl` and `sysctl dev.ixl.1.iflib`.

Your current output from `dmesg` was:

```
ixl0: pxm cpus: 8 queue msgs: 128 admincnt: 1
ixl0: using 8 rx queues 8 tx queues

ixl1: pxm cpus: 8 queue msgs: 128 admincnt: 1
ixl1: using 8 rx queues 8 tx queues
```

You claim you have done all this before to no avail.

If we look in the bug report for [Bug 230465 - ixl: not working in netmap mode](https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=230465) we do however get confirmation from [Jeff Pieper](https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=230465#c29). [Charles Goncalves](https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=230465#c31) further confirms that it works for him.

This is a rather typical way of setting things in FreeBSD and usually works. As always it *could* be a buggy driver but with the above confirmation I think not. I do not have an ixl card so unfortunately I cannot confirm anything.

You mention `kenv` as well. And [Jeff Pieper](https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=230465#c32) does confirm this can be set. But note you can only use `kenv` when working with a driver module and not the static driver in the kernel!

So with the above I would claim that it "ShouldWork(tm)" with settings in `loader.conf` with the kernel driver in FreeBSD 12 (or later). And it is a reminder to almost always add `uname -a` to any FreeBSD related questions .

## Desperate times - desperate measures

You also reported `dev.ixl.1.iflib.driver_version: 2.1.0-k`. I assume this is the static kernel version of the driver. According to the [ixl](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ixl&sektion=4) man page the upstream driver from Intel is updated more frequently and is supplied in [net/intel-ixl-kmod](https://www.freshports.org/net/intel-ixl-kmod/).

If you want to go this route - then make sure that you have populated `/usr/src` and have an up-to-date [ports](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/ports-using.html) tree. There is not a pre-built package available.

To install the kmod driver:

```
cd /usr/ports/net/intel-ixl-kmod/ && make install clean
```

Make sure `/boot/loader.conf` looks like this:

```
dev.ixl.1.iflib.override_qs_enable=1
dev.ixl.1.iflib.override_nrxqs=16
dev.ixl.1.iflib.override_ntxqs=16
if_ixl_updated_load="YES"
```

Reboot and see effects in dmesg and sysctl.

When using this modular driver you can also set the environment dynamicly using `kenv` as [Jeff Pieper](https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=230465#c32) described. Unload and load the driver using `kldunload` and `kldload`

## Interrupt storms

I noticed that you had:

```
hw.intr_storm_threshold: 1000
```

But as it is only a X710 for 10GbE it is probably not a problem. According to the [ixl](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ixl&sektion=4) man page you might see interrupt storms at 40GbE. Then you would set:

/etc/sysctl.conf:

```
 hw.intr_storm_threshold=0
```

(hence the interest in this parameter)

## Firmware

And lastly I noticed:

```
dev.ixl.1.fw_version: fw 5.0.40043 api 1.5 nvm 5.05 etid 80002927 oem 1.261.0
```

That firmware is more than two years old. There is a [version 6.80 available for the Intel(R) Ethernet Controller X710](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/24769/Non-Volatile-Memory-NVM-Update-Utility-for-Intel-Ethernet-Converged-Network-Adapter-XL710-and-X710-Series?product=83965)

The easy route is to go with [sysutils/intel-nvmupdate](https://www.freshports.org/sysutils/intel-nvmupdate/). In can be installed quickly as a binary package (no need to build).

Comment: I did remove quotes but it seems that changes are still not persistent.. On boot nor in `/var/log/console.log` I have no warning about wrong setup of there variables.
But I think I'm on the right path now, watch EDIT #2 in my original question..

Comment: Did you see the change when restarting sysctl? And do you have multiple cards? The first card is 0 (ixl0)

Comment: When I do sysctl restart, no change happens..
I do have multiple cards (exactly 2), both with 2 ports.. ifconfig shows ix0, ix1, ixl0, ixl1 - ixl1 is the one I need to setup for sure

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.. As you mentioned, this setup should help. So I focused on the loading of variables, and find out, that in GRUB I had wrong setup of loader, so loader.conf file had no efect..